# Modifying Hudson Changelog

Tags: hudson, jenkins

When using one of the standard Hudson Source Control Management plugins, by default the changes since your last Hudson build are collected and displayed in "Recent Changes."

Our build has one base repository, and then sub-modules are in their own repository.  We use our SCM to pull the base repository.  Then, sub-modules can be pulled using our own customized scripts.  When you commit a change to the sub-module, a comment is logged basically saying "User X modified files x, y, and z: ".  But, this commit is only registered in the base repository with "User X rolled up a change".  Thus, when Hudson collects the changes, only the changes in our base repository are collected, and thus we don't get all of the details about each commit that would have been displayed in the sub-modules.

I've noticed that in the "lastSuccessful" folder there is a "changelog.xml" file containing the changes from our base repository.  I've experimented with modifying the descriptions/list of files, but it doesn't seem to update the "Recent Changes" displayed by Hudson.  Outside of writing my own plugin, is there any way to write my own change log that Hudson will accept?

For example, I would like to add a build step where I run my own script to collect the detailed list of recent changes from the sub-modules.  Then, I would take the output from that script and somehow feed it into Hudson.  But, the question is, where do I feed that output into Hudson?  Or is it even possible at this stage?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you could use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to pull in your "sub-modules". You'll find much better support for them in Hudson/Jenkins than your bespoke scripts

Answer (score 0):

What SCM are you using? For instance with subversion you could use svn:externals in the base-project to include other sub-modules. We've setup our project this way and Hudson/Jenkins would display the changes quite well.

Comment: You should mention some of the [issues using of svn:externals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338824/are-subversion-externals-an-antipattern) before recommending them.