# Switch svn:externals repo?

Tags: svn

Lets say I have a link to `svn://another/repo/tags/1.0` and the author has updated the repo to `svn://another/repo/tags/1.1` how would I change my svn:externals property to point to the new repo?

I'm looking for an `svn switch` style, so that the new repo `updates` over the top.

Would a better answer be to have a branch called "live_branch" or similar, and just update this to the latest version each time?

Thanks

```
> svn propget svn:externals .
1.0 svn://another/repo/tags/1.0
```

Comment: this talks about updating relative externals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439666/svnswitch-doesnt-work-with-relative-svnexternal

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't help me. My externals are absolute and external. :)

Comment: BTW: What kind of programming language are you using in this case ? Perl, PHP, Ruby, C++, Java ?

Comment: The question isn't programming language related. However, the repo is for a Wordpress installation and so therefore PHP.

Comment: I know but based on the programming language there existing different solutions for this kind of problem (PHP pear, Java Maven/Gradle etc.) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The switch command will only change your working copy to use a different URL (trunk/branches/tags) than before...but will not automatically change the svn:externals information...

In your case that means you have to manually update the svn:externals value (change from tags/1.0 to tags/1.1) and test you software with the new state the library you are using)...after testing is finished you can checkin the new svn:externals value.

I would recommend to to something different that the tags value in your external as you mentioned as example.

I would suggest to use a thing:

```
lib svn://another/repos/tags/1.0
```

So the *lib* will not change after changing to another tag (e.g. 1.1) instead...