# How can I make a release with SVN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn

we have been working on a project, now a part of the project is ready to be released internally. So I want to build this release with tortoisesvn. but I haven't work with any release yet. So here I am to get the guideline from you. I am working on a web project with ms vs2008 with c#

Comment: tortoisesvn is a subversion client. That's a _source control system_, **not** a _build system_. You seem to be very confused about what SVN is.

Comment: He might just be asking how to check out a tag or branch of a release so he can build it; seeing as he says he's not worked with it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN wont build a release but you manage your repository carefully, then you might have a 'Tags' folder that lets you mark your release code (it's one of the SVN Red book best practices IIRC)

If that's the case, you simple use TortoiseSVN to checkout that tag to your workstation where you can use your tools, VS in release mode and Publish, or perhaps MSBuild to make your binary package.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to create a release branch to setup a sort of milestone in the source code.  This allows you to go back to the source code that was released at that point in time.

Here's an answer in SO that has some good tips on this.

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184115/svn-release-branch-and-externals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184115/svn-release-branch-and-externals)

Comment: Indeed, maintaining a Tags folder with releases and cuts is a great thing to do! +1

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion there are 3 main folders.

1. Branches
2. Tags
3. Trunk

In branches there are active development nodes and Trunk is the most upto date version. All the branches should be merged forward to Trunk in timely manner. Tags are the released versions. That's a very brief introduction. You can find more documentations [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html).

If you want to release any branch you have to merge forward it into Trunk first and Tag with the release version. Normally do 'copyTo' a new release node in Tag folder. Hope this is what you asked about releasing...